# How to calculate the dates (calculate age) in PHP (dates are stored in Unix Time)?

Tags: php

It is necessary to calculate age based on date of birth. Information on date of birth is stored in the database in Unix Time.

I do not know PHP, has only just started to edit my existing code to get what I need.

Example:

```
$tpl->set( '{birthday}', langdate( "D M Y", $row['birthday'] ) );
```

Displays available in a CMS tag **{birthday}** for date of birth, takes Unix Time value from a database's row **birthday** and converts to a clear view "**D**ate **M**onth **Y**ear".

I want to create available in CMS tag **{age}** and through him publish age.

I suppose something like this:

```
$tpl->set( '{age}', current date - $row['birthday'] ) );
```

But how to do it - no idea ...

Comment: You need to create a `DateTime` object which has handy methods to operate with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // Today in UNIX Timestamp
$birthday = strtotime(date('D M Y', strtotime($row['birthday']))); // Birthday in UNIX Timestamp
$age = $now - $birthday; // As the UNIX Timestamp is in seconds, get the seconds you lived
$age = $age / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365; // Convert seconds to years
echo floor($age); // Round down to whole integer and echo it
?>
```

This is in my opinion the easiest way to calculate with dates as its easy to calculate with seconds. Not much of using the brain is needed :)

But the more beautifull way is:

```
<?php
$birthday = new DateTime($row['birthday']);
$now = new DateTime();
$age = $now->diff($birthday);
echo $age -> y;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand, what means **y** in the end of this code? :)

Comment: `$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));` replace it with time(). Also try date under 1970-01-01 with first example ;)

Comment: Great, I'm 64 and your code tells me I'm 54...

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in the query with

`SELECT .. TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, FROM_UNIXTIME(dob), NOW()) as AGE ..`

Comment: I know the OP asked for "php" solution but this is the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
echo date("Y", time()) - date("Y", $birth_in_unix_format);
```